# PostgreSQL : Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I execute my query I have this error :

> Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: "GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_histo" > timestamp without time zone Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 176

Here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT *
FROM "GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic"
WHERE "GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic.PO_Creation_date" > 
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

I work on PostgreSQL database.
I think the problem comes from the PO_Creation_date type but I don't understand that it should be cast since it is in date format

Comment: The issue probably arises from delimiting tables and columns that don't need delimiting; remove the quotes.

Comment: `"GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic.PO_Creation_date"` should be: `"GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic"."PO_Creation_date"` (each elements needs to quoted individually) Pro tip: if you use aliases you don't need to repeat that long table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `::DATE`

```
SELECT *
FROM "GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic"
WHERE "GOOD_RECIEPT_ANOMALY_DETECTION_V2_last_alerts_sent_gsheet_historic"."PO_Creation_date"::DATE > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month'
```